# How to filter in laravel using middleware?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to finer all active courses and here is what I've tried.

Middleware is called Status

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      $status = $request->status();
      if($status == 'active'){
        return view('admin.courses.index');
      }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

My route calls the middleware

```
Route::get('admin/courses/?active', 'Admin\CoursesController@index')->middleware('status');
```

My view has a button that calls the route

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.courses.index') }}" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-success">
            Active <span class="badge badge-light">{{$course_count_active}}</span>
          <span class="sr-only">total courses</span></a>
```

This code is not filtering the records and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: if you need to find all courses then why not find them in controller? also you're not passing the route parameter correctly and you're named route is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the correct syntax for giving parameter is `{parameter?}`

Now second want to ask you did you register your middleware in `kernel.php` file (i guess you did but still need to confirm)

now your button giving no parameter to route

```
{{ route('admin.courses.index') }}
```

which means your middleware will run `$next($request)`

so if you need to see the view part(which you saying filter) , do it like that `{{ route('admin.courses.index',['status'=>'active']) }}`

now last give named route, if you don't give name route then you can't call `route()`, give name route like below

```
Route::get('admin/courses/{status?}', 'Admin\CoursesController@index')->name('admin.courses.index')->middleware('status');
```

and give parameter name `status` like above

*Update*

Another mistake you can't get parameter as you did.

```
$status = $request->status();
```

simply write below

```
$status = $request->status;
```

**Update**

So now you facing error `setCooking on member function` because you `return view('someview')` form middleware which is not a good practice at all.

in the middleware use `redirect()` to some route.
so I suggest you make a route in which you return view.

and redirect to this route from middleware will solve your problem.

Comment: any Errors you face?

Comment: well his middleware is incorrect. thats not how you get route params

Comment: can you explain @AdityaThakur . I guess he get route parameter correctly. let me know if am wrong

Comment: his middleware will throw error `undefined method status()`

Comment: oh yes, I did not chcek carefully, ill update my answer

Comment: thank you so much for your response, now I'm getting the following error Call to a member function setCookie() on null

Comment: @SimonaBuga `return view()` from middleware is throwing this error, use `return redirect()`

Comment: I need to use the same index view, because I'm trying to filter just the active records, if I do redirect then I get just the admin.courses.index and a 404 page

Comment: create a route for your admin.courses.index view, and redirect to that route @SimonaBuga

Comment: I've created a route and then redirected it in the middleware return redirect()->route('admin.courses.index'); and the route is Route::get('admin/courses/', 'Admin\CoursesController@index'); I don't get an error but I still can't filter

Comment: @SimonaBuga `Route::get('admin/courses/', 'Admin\CoursesController@index')->name('admin.courses.index');`

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try tonight when I get home.

Comment: The page refreshes, the active is passed through but the results do not filter.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days I realized I was missing the csfr token. Here is what I've modified and now it works.

Form - blade

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

In the Ajax script:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: method,
        data: {
        "_token": $('#token').val(),
        'item':$('#item').val(),
        "description": $('#description').val(),
      },

        success: function(response) {

        },

        error: function(xhr) {

      var error = xhr.responseJSON;
      if ($.isEmptyObject(error) == false) {
          $.each(error.errors, function(key, value) {
            $('#' + key)
              .closest('.form-group')
              .addClass('has-error')
              .append('<span class="help-block"><strong>' + value + '</strong></span>')

          });
      }
    }
```